# How to determine if it's possible to draw a graph $G$ with a given set of vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

> Given a list of vertices associated with its degree, says:
>   $$7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1$$
>   Determine whether it is possible to draw a graph $G$, where $G$ is connected and un-directed.

**Solution**: The above graph is impossible to draw because the first two vertices will make every other vertices have degree 2.
But I realize this approach is too specific, and it's not feasible if the given list is large, let's say $n > 100$, where $n$ is the number of vertices. So my question is, if a general list of $n$ vertices is given with a degree from $1 \rightarrow n - 1$, then is there a general formula to determine whether it is possible to draw its graph? Thank you.

Comment: If you are not restricting yourself to simple graphs, the only thing you need to check is whether the sum of the degrees is even or not.

Comment: @Shahab: Thank you. However, $G$ must be connected, and undirected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not enough for the sums of the degrees of the vertices to be even. A simple counterexample is 2,2,2,4.

I know of 2 common algorithms that can be used to determine whether or not a list of integers represents a valid degree sequence. They are the [Erdos-Gallai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) Theorem and the [Havel-Hakimi](http://books.google.com/books?id=K6-FvXRlKsQC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=havel-hakimi+theorem+chartrand&source=bl&ots=Xy5emhh69J&sig=v3bKpI8L8ZkhlqtPH3UAkveNLUw&hl=en&ei=VPxeTtWAGcXfiAK6luyrDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q&f=false) Theorem.

I believe that generally Havel-Hakimi is a little easier to implement and a quick google search turns up several different existing programs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those info.

Comment: I wonder how different it will be on the sequence after applying Havel-Hakimi algorithm because my graph is connected?

Comment: @Chan Both algorithms are intended to operate on connected components so the Havel-Hakimi algorithm will work perfectly on your connected graph.

Comment: Hi Robert Wiberg again, I've just encountered one particular sequence today and I think it won't work on connected components. For example, $3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1$, it satisfied Havel-Hakimi, but when I graph it, it is not connected.

Comment: @Chan The algorithm also works on both components separately. You are right though, even if you have a disconnected graph the algorithm works both on the components individually and on the entire sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29)

In general if one allows any type of graph, then a sequence whose sum of degrees is even will have a graph, and any sequence whose sum of degrees is odd will not have a graph.

If you wish to impose extra conditions on the type of graph, then the problem appears much harder

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wonder what could be the condition to verify a connected graph is drawable?

Comment: You may be interested in [this paper](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/1579/1579A.pdf).

Comment: Nice paper, thanks a lot.